# How to convert a formated string into a one element tuple?

Tags: string, python-3.x, tuples

It is possible to convert a single formatted string into a tuple, for example I am trying to transform a return from a function into a tuple.

E.g:

```
def GCcontent(self):
    "Return GC content of the sequence given"
    A = self.get_secuencia().count('A')
    T = self.get_secuencia().count('T')
    C = self.get_secuencia().count('C') 
    G = self.get_secuencia().count('G')
    content = '{0:.2f}%'.format((G+C)*100/(A+T+G+C))

    return content
```

The output is:

```
'XX.XX%'
```

But what I want to get is the following output:

```
('XX.XX%')
```

Is this even possible?. I tried tuple() function but it doesn't work as expected, is there another method to achieve this?

Comment: What does "doesn't work as expected" mean?  *How* did you try to use `tuple`?

Comment: tuple(content) was my first attempt, but then I tried some other methods as str(' '.join(content)) but it was a failure too...

Comment: "Failure" in what way?  How was what you got different than what you wanted?

Comment: what i got by using tuple(content) was a tuple wich multiple strings as given: ('X','X', '.', 'X', 'X', '%') buy what Im looking for is ('XX.XX%')

Comment: try `(content, )`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tuple([content])` will yield a 1-element tuple whose element is the string in `content`, but note that when printed, it appears as

```
('XX.XX%',)
```

Comment: So it is impossible to just get ('XX.XX%') without that ',' at the end?

Comment: What do you mean by "get"?

Comment: what I mean is to get an output as ('XX.XX%') without the comma...

Comment: What you "get" is a tuple as you requested; how it gets displayed depends on how you display it.